# node.js httpntlm keeps returning a 401

Tags: javascript, node.js, ntlm

I've calling a windows REST service which requires NTLM. When I call the service using a utility like SOAP-UI and supply my credentials for NTLM authorization it works fine, I get a result. when I use httpnltm (https://www.npmjs.org/package/httpntlm) to accomplish this from node.js I always get a 401 error, with the following message: "You do not have permission to view this directory or page.". The get options set are exactly the same used in SOAP-UI and it works there.

```
httpntlm.get({
    url: 'endpoint',
    username: 'my_username',
    password: 'my_password',
    domain: 'my_domain'
}, function (err, res){
    if(err){
        callback(err.message, null);
    }else{
        if(res.statusCode == 401){
            // always the case!
        }
    }
});
```

Is there something I am missing from this get request?

Comment: Did you get any solution?